# Relative pathway inconsistency in VS code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, filepath

I've recently moved to a dual boot  Windows/Ubuntu system and have shared my scripts and VScode workspaces between the two.

Because I am working between two different OS I made sure to change all my file paths to use relative paths rather than absolute paths. However they all seem broken in VScode un ubuntu.

I made a simple file structure to try and work out what the issue is but I've not had any luck

```
- Directory1:
  - csv1.csv
  - Directory2:
    - csv1.csv
    - test.py
```

For test.py, I wrote a super simple script to load the csv files into a Pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.read_csv("../csv1.csv")

print(df)
```

`df = pd.read_csv("../csv1.csv")`This relative path works in  Ubuntu shell , Windows cmd and  VS code (on windows)

`df1 = pd.read_csv("Directory1/Directory2/csv2.csv")`   This relative path works in VS code ( in Ubuntu)

I'm pretty stuck for what to do, I've tried search around. If i open up the same workspace in VScode (in Ubuntu) and try and reference a file in the same directory I get an error informing me it doens't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use Path objects from the standard library pathlib rather than regular strings

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

That will keep the differences between Posix and Windows from causing these problems

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

p = Path('..') / 'csv1.csv'

df  = pd.read_csv(p)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Jim , I tried your suggestion however I still get the same error.


Whilst this command works fine in  Ubuntu terminal , Windows cmd and VScode on windows

```df  = pd.read_csv("../dir1.csv")```

to get an output in VScode on Ubuntu i need

```df  = pd.read_csv("Dir1/dir1.csv")```

Comment: It may be because it's running with a different working directory between the Ubuntu and Windows versions. You could add a `print(os.getcwd())` to see

Comment: I Think I've got it solved ! Thank you for your help. I think It was running in the open folder rather than file Dir.

I ended up going back to the first Python tutorial I ever did and realised I had to tick a box  "execute in file dir".